# How to delete all data after the third colon in strings/ substrings in R?

Tags: r

So I have a series of about 200,000 data points that look like this: `DATA:abc:de123fg:12ghk8d` and `DATA:ghi:56kdv:128485hg`. The only identifying data that I need to look at is before the third colon. I want to remove everything after the third colon so I can aggregate unique identifiers from the rest of the substring..

So far, I have attempted to use `str_remove_all` and `gsub` to remove everything after the third colon. The problem with this is that sometimes the data points are grouped together in the same string like this:

`DATA:ghi:56kdv:128485hg`|`DATA:abc:de123fg:12ghk8d`

So string_remove_all is just removing the end of the last substring and it ends up looking like this:

`DATA:ghi:56kdv:128485hg`|`DATA:abc:de123fg`

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this task? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option in base R with `regmatches` and `regexpr`:

```r
str <- c("DATA:abc:de123fg:12ghk8d", "DATA:ghi:56kdv:128485hg|DATA:abc:de123fg:12ghk8d")

regmatches(str, regexpr("[^:]*:[^:]*", str)) 
#> [1] "DATA:abc" "DATA:ghi"
```

And the corresponding solution in `stringr`, if you prefer:

```r
library(stringr)

str_extract(str, "[^:]*:[^:]*")
#> [1] "DATA:abc" "DATA:ghi"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>